# Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '[2].id'

Tags: reactjs

Estoy llenado una lista en react en donde paso ciertos valores con un for, y por alguna razon detecta valores null y no puedo validar que si sean null no los añada a la lista.
Intenté con un If pero no funciona.
Los valores se estan añadiendo como NaN

```html
 const [respuesta,setRespuesta]=useState({
      idPregunta:parseInt(),
      idRelacion:parseInt()
    });
const [respuestas, setRespuestas]=useState([]);

const handleChange=e=>{ 
      const {name, value}=e.target;    
      setRespuesta(prevState=>({
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value
      }));   
    } 
    
  const guardar=e=>{
      e.preventDefault()
  
       for (i in respuesta) {  
        if(respuesta[i]!=NaN){ 
        let data = { idPregunta: parseInt(i), idRelacion: parseInt(respuesta[i]) };
        respuestas.push(data);  
        }      
      }    
    
     peticionPost();
     setRespuestas([]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes comprabar si esta vacio o si es undefined o si es null negando a la variable
asi que esto:

```
  if(respuesta[i]!=NaN){ 
        let data = { idPregunta: parseInt(i), idRelacion: parseInt(respuesta[i]) };
        respuestas.push(data);  
        }
```

cambialo por simplemente:

```
if(!respuesta[i]){ 
        let data = { idPregunta: parseInt(i), idRelacion: parseInt(respuesta[i]) };
        respuestas.push(data);  
        }
```